# Freak behiaviour of my laptop audio card

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

The audio card of my laptop sometimes works after boot and sometimes not. I even tried to plug into it the jack of my 90' stereo integrated amplifier or headphones and nothing changed in settings and neither sound started to work.
Every time I boot Ubuntu I see that the type and icon of sound card changes into another, while sometimes the output is normal as it represents headphones or speakers from the computer, other times I see the icon of TV speaker (HDMI was never used in this case, but I use my laptop connected to a 17" 4:3 monitor via VGA) and other times once I see "dummy output". In any case that, mentioned before audio it's not working at all, only barely and randomly and it shows the real output of audio in settings, for example, if I use it with the amplifier it shows me headphones because amplifier it is going to be recognized as headphones. I have root access to the system so if I need to install some diagnostic tools provided by you it is not a problem. The audio card is obviously the one integrated on my laptop.

My system specs:

- Laptop: HP 250 G3
- OS: Ubuntu 18.10 cosmic
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.18.0-10-generic
- Resolution: 1280x1024
- DE: GNOME
- CPU: Intel Core i5-4210U
- RAM: 8GB
- VGA: Integrated on CPU